Flask API streaming chunk size
I have a Python Flask API which is set to return text responses in streaming fashion. Here is the stub of the end point
def streaming_endpoint(): 
    params = parse_request(request)  
    def generate():
        for chunks in generate_streaming(params):
            yield chunks + "*"
    return Response(response=generate(),mimetype='text/plain')

I am calling the API via cURL as:
curl -N -X POST -F "file=@myfile.csv" 'https://myurl.com/streaming_endpoint?param1=p1'

The above call returns/prints chunks of text which are bigger than the chunks yield by the Flask API. That is, assuming the text is: "This is an example output returned by the Flask API in a streaming fashion", what I get is:

First chunk: This* is* an* example* output*
Second chunk: returned* by* the* Flask* API*
Third chunk: in* a* streaming* fashion*.

Rather than:

First chunk: This*
Second chunk: is*
Third chunk: an*

I assume that by using -N there is no buffer, hence, each chunk sent by the Flask API should be immediately be displayed. Is there something that needs to be changed from the Flask API? What could be the best approach to allow the printing of each chunk (or word)?
